# Default Values with Interface in Arrow Function (TypeScript, React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

This question is specific to arrow functions. Is it possible to include the default values alongside an interface in the function parameters, and without resorting to Object.assign()?

```
interface Props {
  someBoolean?: boolean;
  anotherBoolean?: boolean;
  children: any;
}

const DefaultValues = {
  someBoolean: false,
  anotherBoolean: false,
}

export const StackOverflow: React.FC<Props> = (_props: Props) => {
  const props = Object.assign({}, _props, DefaultValues);

  return <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

Comment: `const props = Object.assign({}, _props, DefaultValues);` does not seem correct. `DefaultValues` will overwrite every existing prop in `_props` . Should change the order to `Object.assign({}, DefaultValues, _props);`

Answer (score 1):

IFF you don't need `DefaultValues` elsewhere and you don't need to be able to refer to (all of the) `props` in the body of your function, then yes:

```js
export const StackOverflow: React.FC<Props> = ({ someBoolean = false,
  anotherBoolean = false, children = [], ...additionalProps }) => {

  return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

Comment: Actually you can refer to props using spread properties `{ someBoolean = false,  anotherBoolean = false, children = [], ...props }`

Comment: @SeanVieira Thank you for your reply. Could you explain why you use the interface for `React.FC<Props>` but not in the parameter setup, like this `({someBoolean = false, ...additionalProps}: Props)`?

Comment: Because the type of `React.FC<T>` approximates `T => ReactElementTypes` and if any function _definition_ is going to match that type signature it must either be `() => ReactElementTypes` (take no arguments) _or_ take a single argument of the type `T`.  And if the argument _must_ be `T`, then there's no point (in my mind) of saying the same thing twice.  ("The variable `StackOverflow` is a function from `MyPropType` to `Element`, to which we assign a function which takes a `MyPropType` and returns `Element`", vs. "The variable `StackOverflow` is a function from `MyPropType` to `Element`").

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the defaults in a functional way, by composing your component.

```
interface Props {
  someBoolean: boolean;
  anotherBoolean: boolean;
  children: any;
}

const StackOverflow: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>;
};

function withDefaults<T extends React.ComponentType<any>, U extends Partial<React.ComponentProps<T>>>(
  Component: T,
  defaults: U,
): React.FunctionComponent<Omit<React.ComponentProps<T>, keyof U> & Partial<U>> {
  // @see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14729
  return props => React.createElement(Component, { ...defaults, ...props });
}
```

Usage:

```
const StackOverflowWithDefaults = withDefaults(StackOverflow, { someBoolean: false, anotherBoolean: false });

<StackOverflowWithDefaults>
  The only prop I need to provide is children
</StackOverflowWithDefaults>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Answer is no. You cannot add some default `value` to an `interface` or `type`

But you can do something like this.

```
interface SomeType {
     prop1: string;
     prop2: number;
     prop3?: boolean; // optional
}

const fun = (value: SomeType) => {

// Assigning default value to the prop3 which is optional.
   const {prop1, prop2, prop3 = false} = value;

}
```